# why adding this svg component to react doesn't work correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I want to integrate this svg element

```html
<div width="330" height="200" style="background-color: #FAFAFA">
<div width="330" height="100" style="background-color: #FAFAFA">
</div>
<svg width="330" height="110">
    <g transform="translate(20, 0)">
        <rect width="280" height="50" style="fill: url(&quot;#myGradient&quot;);"></rect>
        <g fill="none" font-size="10" font-family="sans-serif" text-anchor="middle">
            <g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(0.5,0)">
                <line stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" y2="60"></line>
                <text style="font-size:20px" fill="currentColor" y="63" dy="0.71em">0</text>
            </g>
            <g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(92.9,0)">
                <line stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" y2="60"></line>
                <text style="font-size:20px" fill="currentColor" y="63" dy="0.71em">33</text>
            </g>
            <g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(92.9,0)">
                <line stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" y2="60"></line>
                <text style="font-size:20px" fill="currentColor" y="63" dy="0.71em">33</text>
            </g>
            <g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(185.3,0)">
                <line stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" y2="60"></line>
                <text style="font-size:20px" fill="currentColor" y="63" dy="0.71em">66</text>
            </g>
            <g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(185.3,0)">
                <line stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" y2="60"></line>
                <text style="font-size:20px" fill="currentColor" y="63" dy="0.71em">66</text>
            </g>
            <g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(280.5,0)">
                <line stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" y2="60"></line>
                <text style="font-size:20px" fill="currentColor" y="63" dy="0.71em">100</text>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="myGradient">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FFFFFF"></stop>
            <stop offset="3%" stop-color="#FFFFFF"></stop>
            <stop offset="3%" stop-color="#00B050"></stop>
            <stop offset="30%" stop-color="#00B050"></stop>
            <stop offset="30%" stop-color="#FFFFFF"></stop>
            <stop offset="36%" stop-color="#FFFFFF"></stop>
            <stop offset="36%" stop-color="#FFA500"></stop>
            <stop offset="63%" stop-color="#FFA500"></stop>
            <stop offset="63%" stop-color="#FFFFFF"></stop>
            <stop offset="69%" stop-color="#FFFFFF"></stop>
            <stop offset="69%" stop-color="#D0021B"></stop>
            <stop offset="97%" stop-color="#D0021B"></stop>
            <stop offset="97%" stop-color="#FFFFFF"></stop>
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FFFFFF"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
</svg>

</div>
```

as a react component:

```
import React, { Component as ReactComponent } from "react";

export default class RiskLegend extends ReactComponent {
    render() {
        return (
            <div width="330" height="200" style={{ backgroundColor: "#FAFAFA" }}>

<! –– The SVG element above ––>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

but the result appears to be not correct as in the screenshots. I don't know where is the problem. I changed the style attributes to follow react style.

this is the what appears after adding it to react

[image: after adding to react]

this is the Original SVG element:

[image: Original SVG element]

Comment: Remember, JSX is not HTML. You can't interchange them and expect it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have inline style in your JSX written in the wrong way, inline style should be an object, here is a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-sea-bd3r8?file=/src/App.js), and a snippet:

```
<div className="App">
  <div width="330" height="200" style={{ "background-color": "#FAFAFA" }}>
    <div
      width="330"
      height="100"
      style={{ "background-color": "#FAFAFA" }}
    />
    <svg width="330" height="110">
      <g transform="translate(20, 0)">
        <rect
          width="280"
          height="50"
          style={{ fill: "url('#myGradient')" }}
        />
        <g
          fill="none"
          font-size="10"
          font-family="sans-serif"
          text-anchor="middle"
        >
          <g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(0.5,0)">
            <line stroke="currentColor" strokeWidth="2" y2="60" />
            <text
              style={{ fontSize: "20px" }}
              fill="currentColor"
              y="63"
              dy="0.71em"
            >
              0
            </text>
          </g>
          <g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(92.9,0)">
            <line stroke="currentColor" strokeWidth="2" y2="60" />
            <text
              style={{ fontSize: "20px" }}
              fill="currentColor"
              y="63"
              dy="0.71em"
            >
              33
            </text>
          </g>
          <g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(92.9,0)">
            <line stroke="currentColor" strokeWidth="2" y2="60" />
            <text
              style={{ fontSize: "20px" }}
              fill="currentColor"
              y="63"
              dy="0.71em"
            >
              33
            </text>
          </g>
          <g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(185.3,0)">
            <line stroke="currentColor" strokeWidth="2" y2="60" />
            <text
              style={{ fontSize: "20px" }}
              fill="currentColor"
              y="63"
              dy="0.71em"
            >
              66
            </text>
          </g>
          <g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(185.3,0)">
            <line stroke="currentColor" strokeWidth="2" y2="60" />
            <text
              style={{ fontSize: "20px" }}
              fill="currentColor"
              y="63"
              dy="0.71em"
            >
              66
            </text>
          </g>
          <g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(280.5,0)">
            <line stroke="currentColor" strokeWidth="2" y2="60" />
            <text
              style={{ fontSize: "20px" }}
              fill="currentColor"
              y="63"
              dy="0.71em"
            >
              100
            </text>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="myGradient">
          <stop offset="0%" stopColor="#FFFFFF" />
          <stop offset="3%" stopColor="#FFFFFF" />
          <stop offset="3%" stopColor="#00B050" />
          <stop offset="30%" stopColor="#00B050" />
          <stop offset="30%" stopColor="#FFFFFF" />
          <stop offset="36%" stopColor="#FFFFFF" />
          <stop offset="36%" stopColor="#FFA500" />
          <stop offset="63%" stopColor="#FFA500" />
          <stop offset="63%" stopColor="#FFFFFF" />
          <stop offset="69%" stopColor="#FFFFFF" />
          <stop offset="69%" stopColor="#D0021B" />
          <stop offset="97%" stopColor="#D0021B" />
          <stop offset="97%" stopColor="#FFFFFF" />
          <stop offset="100%" stopColor="#FFFFFF" />
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also `class` should be `className` in JSX elements